# React native app keeps an old version in release

Tags: react-native

I have made many changes in my js code, when I run in debug mode I'm able to see all the changes but when I run the app in release mode or generate a release apk, the changes that were made and visible in debug mode are not visible.

What I have already tried?

```
react-native run-android --variant=release
```

> Deleted the builds folder and android.bundle.js in assets

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Run the below command before you run release variant in the project directory.

So command sequence will be first execute

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

This may take little time to finsh.

Then execute your run command:

```
react-native run-android --variant=release
```

Comment: Thanks for your help buddy, I have already fixed it by using the same command from another solution

Comment: Glad to hear @Ammar

Comment: Creating the final js bundle with all updated code using different options and put that bundle in android's assets folder.

Comment: Just run across same issue. Would love to know why this happens and why the bundle command is required